# Multiple products, different units, one inventory

Tags: inventory, magmi, stock

The scenario is as follows:

Product A, SKU 1000, sold as 1 roll of 1000 meters of cable, price 800 euro
Product B, SKU 1000, sold per meter of cable, price 1 euro

Those products should share the same inventory, if one piece of product A is sold, the available quantity of both products should be reduced automatically (product A by 1, product B by 1000). If 500 pieces of product B are sold, the available quantity of both products should be reduced automatically (product A by 1, product B by 500).

So its like this: multiple products, same SKU, different units, same inventory.

I am working with Magmi to import products into Magento so I think using a 3rd party plugin is not an option here. Whats the best solution in this case? I have done quite some research but haven't found how to tackle this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are my 2 cents. 
Since A & B have the same SKU and should share the same inventory, why not make it a single product?
This way the stock is reduced correctly when you buy X meters.
If the price for product A is not 1000 * price of B then you can easily manage this with tire prices.
Create a tire price where customer group is `ALL GROUPS` and Qty is 1000 and set the appropriate price.
The prices should be per meter.

Comment: Hi Marius, thanks for the reply. Yet I dont understand how I can let the customer make a choice between meters and roll. Should I look at configurable products then?

Comment: You don't let them choose. Just add a message in the product description saying 1000m = 1 roll. and if they want a roll they fill in 1000 for qty.

Comment: I have implemented it like this and it works fine. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion by @Marius looks like a good suggestion especially with your scenario but with our scenario it was bit different than yours.

We are selling cups with different colours and sizes where customers can choose size from S, M, L, XL and 36 different colours but our base size "cups" has one inventory. So when Small size cup get sold in any of the 36 different colours then we wanted to update the inventory of small base "cup" so that we can maintain how many small cups can be sold on our website.

We were looking out for the solution and found the closest solution for Magento 2 is the following extension

[Magento 2 Associated Product](https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-2-associated-or-linked-product-stock-update.html)

This might not be useful for you but it might help others where they have similar scenario than ours